# BFS to check if a graph is bipartite in c++

Tags: c++, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, bipartite

I am implementing an algorithm to determine whether an undirected graph is bipartite or not. Based on [this pseudo-code](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/GraphAlgor/breadthSearch.htm) made ​​my implementation, which works for graphs connected, but when it is disconnected simply the program indicates a wrong answer. I think if its not connected, then one more loop is needed for every disjoint sub-graph. But im stuck with this. How I can solve my code for me to print a correct answer?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000

int numberVertex, numberEdges;
int particion[MAX], visited[MAX];
vector< int > adjacencyMatrix[MAX];

bool bfs()
{
    int i, origin, destination, begin;
    queue< int > queueVertex;
    begin = 0;
    queueVertex.push(begin);
    particion[begin] = 1; // 1 left,
    visited[begin] = 1; // set adjacencyMatrixray

    while(!queueVertex.empty())
    {
        origin = queueVertex.front(); queueVertex.pop();
        for(i=0; i < adjacencyMatrix[origin].size(); i++)
        {
            destination = adjacencyMatrix[origin][i];
            if(particion[origin] == particion[destination])
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(visited[destination] == 0)
            {
                visited[destination] = 1;
                particion[destination] = 3 - particion[origin]; // alter 1 and 2 subsets
                queueVertex.push(destination);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
 freopen("tarea2.in", "r", stdin);
    int i,j, nodeOrigin, nodeDestination;
    scanf("%d %d", &numberVertex, &numberEdges);
    for(i=0; i<numberEdges; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &nodeOrigin, &nodeDestination);
        adjacencyMatrix[nodeOrigin].push_back(nodeDestination);
        adjacencyMatrix[nodeDestination].push_back(nodeOrigin);
    }
    if(bfs()) {

        printf("Is bipartite\n");
          for (j=0; j<numberVertex; j++){
        cout<<j<<" "<<particion[j]<<endl;
        }

    }
    else {printf("Is not bipartite\n");}





    return 0;
}
```

For example for this input

```
6 4
3 0
1 0
2 5
5 4
```

the output should be:

```
Is bipartite
0 1
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
```

Instead throws me the output:

```
0 1
1 2
2 0
3 2
4 0
5 0
```

This happens because the graph is not a connected graph, ie, has two connected components.I hope you can help me because I've been stuck with this for several days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should run bfs on every connected component. Simplest way to do this is to iterate over all vertices and if they weren't visited, then just call bfs on them.

```
bool is_bipartite()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberVertex; i++)
    {
       if (visited[i] == 0 && !bfs(i)) {
           return false;
       }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

It is still linear because, you run bfs on every connected component once.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000

int numberVertex, numberEdges;
int particion[MAX], visited[MAX];
vector< int > adjacencyMatrix[MAX];

bool bfs(int begin)
{
    int i, origin, destination;
    queue< int > queueVertex;
    queueVertex.push(begin);
    particion[begin] = 1; // 1 left,
    visited[begin] = 1; // set adjacencyMatrixray

    while(!queueVertex.empty())
    {
        origin = queueVertex.front(); queueVertex.pop();
        for(i=0; i < adjacencyMatrix[origin].size(); i++)
        {
            destination = adjacencyMatrix[origin][i];
            if(particion[origin] == particion[destination])
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(visited[destination] == 0)
            {
                visited[destination] = 1;
                particion[destination] = 3 - particion[origin]; // alter 1 and 2 subsets
                queueVertex.push(destination);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool is_bipartite()
{
    for(int i=0; i< numberVertex; i++)
    {
       if (visited[i] == 0 && !bfs(i)) {
           return false;
       }
    } 
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    //freopen("tarea2.in", "r", stdin);
    int i,j, nodeOrigin, nodeDestination;
    scanf("%d %d", &numberVertex, &numberEdges);
    for(i=0; i<numberEdges; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &nodeOrigin, &nodeDestination);
        adjacencyMatrix[nodeOrigin].push_back(nodeDestination);
        adjacencyMatrix[nodeDestination].push_back(nodeOrigin);
    }
    if(is_bipartite()) {

        printf("Is bipartite\n");
          for (j=0; j<numberVertex; j++){
        cout<<j<<" "<<particion[j]<<endl;
        }

    }
    else {printf("Is not bipartite\n");}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The detailed implementation is as follows (C++ version). It will be able to handle several separated connected components.

Assume the graph node is defined as:

```
struct NODE
{
    int color;
    vector<int> neigh_list;
};
```

Then you can check whether the whole graph is `bipartite` by calling `bfs()`.

```
bool checkAllNodesVisited(NODE *graph, int numNodes, int & index);

bool bfs(NODE * graph, int numNodes)
{
    int start = 0;

    do 
    {
        queue<int> Myqueue;
        Myqueue.push(start);
        graph[start].color = 0;

        while(!Myqueue.empty())
        {
            int gid = Myqueue.front();
            for(int i=0; i<graph[gid].neigh_list.size(); i++)
            {
                int neighid = graph[gid].neigh_list[i];
                if(graph[neighid].color == -1)
                {
                    graph[neighid].color = (graph[gid].color+1)%2; // assign to another group
                    Myqueue.push(neighid);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(graph[neighid].color == graph[gid].color) // touble pair in the same group
                        return false;
                }
            }
            Myqueue.pop();
        }
    } while (!checkAllNodesVisited(graph, numNodes, start)); // make sure all nodes visited 
                                            // to be able to handle several separated graphs, IMPORTANT!!!

    return true;
}

bool checkAllNodesVisited(NODE *graph, int numNodes, int & index)
{
    for (int i=0; i<numNodes; i++)
    {
        if (graph[i].color == -1)
        {
            index = i;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bipartite graph is also known as 2-colour graph i.e we can colour all the nodes of the bipartite graph with only 2 colour such that no 2 adjacent node have same colour.

- Initially let all vertex are not having any colour.
- Start with any vertex and colour it with RED. Then Colour its all adjacent    vertices with a colour other than RED let say Black.
- Keep on repeating this
  till all node are coloured. If at any point you found two adjacent
  node have same colour. Then it is not a bipartite graph.

[C++ Implementation](http://www.binarycoder.org/data-structure/check-graph-bipartite-using-bfs/)

Comment: you should enhance your answer by adding some source code